# Encrypt with AES without header

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, aes, redhat

I'm trying to encrypt a 16KiB block with AES.

I tried to do it with openssl, but the size grew from 16384 to 16416. Looks like openssl put a 32B header.

Is there any way to "remove" the 32B header? If it matters, my environment is Redhat 5.11.

Edit: 
I tried only the command line tools of openssl:
Encryption:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -in text.txt -out encrypted.txt
```

Decryption:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in encrypted.txt -out decrypted.txt
```

Also - I need a tool that I can use with C++.

Comment: Show the code, pls.

Comment: Hi, there is no code yet. Just a shell command. Please look at my edit. Thanks!

Comment: *"i need a tool that i can use with C++."* - You mean you need a library to be used in C++? Well, OpenSSL provides one. Also, if you want the ciphertext be of the same size as the plaintext, then you will have lower security, because now the encryption cannot be semantically secure (it needs to be randomized, and that randomization must be stored somewhere).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>No, it did not put a header</s>. It did [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)).

The `AES` is a block cipher with 128 bit block size that requires the length of data being enciphered to be even to the cipher block size. This padding is also used to recover the original data stream length after deciphering.

**Edit:**

According to @jww the openssl lib also prepends the stream with 16byte header containing a magic 8-byte string "Salted__" and and an IV, derived from the password

Comment: Padding explains 16-bytes, but not 32-bytes; there are 16-bytes unaccounted for. Maybe he's using the command line tool and its writing a 16-byte salt/iv? Or maybe its an AuthEnc mode like CCM or GCM, and the additional bytes are a tag.

Comment: @jww That's exactly it. It adds an 8 byte *header* ("Salted__") and an 8 byte salt for key derivation from the given password.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL inserts the "Salted__" header and parameters when it has to generate a key from a user-supplied password. If you specify the key manually using the `-k <key_in_hex>` argument, the header will be omitted.